A stronger form of Cassels's embedding theorem
Let $K$ be a finitely generated field extension of the rational number field $\mathbb{Q}$. Cassels's embedding theorem states that there are infinitely many primes $p$ such that $K$ embeds into $p$-adic fields $\mathbb{Q}_p$. Now, assuming that $K$ is also a topological field, i.e. $K$ is endowed with a topology, can $K$ be continuously embedded into some $p$-adic field?

No. The field of rational numbers with the Archimedean absolute value would have to map via the identity to any $p$-adic field, which is not continuous.
